# How to fix whois Command Error

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, whois

i have Kali Linux version 2016.1 installed on my system. i am trying to run command "whois " but there is an error

"bash: whois: command not found"

Comment: If you are this new to Linux based systems you might well be better off with a more user friendly distribution such as Mint or Ubuntu

Comment: Is there any specific reason for choosing this OS?

Answer (score 5):

`apt-get install whois`

Requires a network connection that can see the kali repo at `http://http.kali.org/`